# Compare dates in query from IMPORTRANGE and cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

for a few days I'm stuck at comparing two dates.

In a big table with dates as columns and products as rows, we want to display the amount of sales per day per product.

What the following query does:

- Import our sales via IMPORTRANGE
- query the specific sales for a given day and product ID
- return 0 if there is an error (e.g. not found)
- count the result

This is a working query with the date 2018-03-26 hard coded:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(query(IMPORTRANGE("1OHR0nr_w3oFNNxtMxRwv65xncCBRpK-vV3vvqmHGFPo"; "Sales March!A:K"); "select Col6 where Col6 = '"&$A95&"' and todate(Col11) = date '2018-03-26'"; 0)))`

It shows how many sales a specific product has on the specified date.

Now I want the date from a cell in the sheet:

`=COUNTA(IFERROR(query(IMPORTRANGE("1OHR0nr_w3oFNNxtMxRwv65xncCBRpK-vV3vvqmHGFPo"; "Sales March!A:K"); "select Col6 where Col6 = '"&$A95&"' and todate(Col11) = date '"&$AR3&"'"; 0)))`

But this doesn't work. I tried A LOT of things for the past 3 days but I have no idea if I did that wrong (I'm a beginner) so I'm turning to you.
What might be wrong with the date comparison in this section?

`"select Col6 where Col6 = '"&$A95&"' and todate(Col11) = date '"&$AR3&"'"`

You can see it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10PjQbTB6bXXrbE_xp1OQ4bGGRIH80J5Nv1_7MAC00hg/edit?usp=sharing) in Column AR Row 95 but I can't give edit rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date provided to `QUERY` must be:

- a string of
- format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Try changing from

```
=date '"&$AR3&"'"; 0)))
```

to

```
=date '"&TEXT($AR3;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 0)))
```

Comment: like this? `"select Col6 where Col6 = '"&$A95&"' and todate(Col11) = '"&TEXT($AR3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"`
=> error while parsing

Comment: thanks for the hint regarding `;`. No errors anymore, but still `0` instead of `2`. This is the complete one:
`=COUNTA(IFERROR(query(IMPORTRANGE("1OHR0nr_w3oFNNxtMxRwv65xncCBRpK-vV3vvqmHGFPo"; "Sales March!A:K"); "select Col6 where Col6 = '"&$A95&"' and todate(Col11) = '"&TEXT($AR3;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 0)))`